# Como atualizar form ou evento do button automaticamente?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Como faço para atualizar um `Private Sub _PAINEL_VENDAS_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load` automaticamente e um evento por exemplo `button`?

Tenho que utilizar um timer?

Comment: Não consegui entender o que você quer fazer, você quer criar um método para quando clicar no botão?

Comment: Quero que chame um botão do form automaticamente a cada 60 segundos.

Comment: Ou gostaria que o form ( load ) se atualize sozinho a cada 60 segundos.

Comment: Peço desculpas por não ter explicado direito e espero que entenda agora.

Answer (score 1):

Experimenta isso:

```vb
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' Aqui seu codigo do botao
    End Sub

    Private Sub _PAINEL_VENDAS_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load    
        Dim timer = New Timer
        timer.Interval = 2 * 1000 ' 2 segundos
        AddHandler timer.Tick, AddressOf Button1_Click
        timer.Start()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Obrigado. Funcionou.

Comment: @user2979215 Se possível selecione minha resposta como a solução para seu problema, assim ajuda novos usuários que cheguem aqui depois.